# Archimate - Technology service - Node relation

Tags: enterprise-architect, archimate

what is the correct "serves" relation between Technology service and Node elements in Archimate 3.0.1?

Regarding metamodel (http://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate3-doc/chap10.html) Service serves to Node (Service -> Node).

But Sparx Enterprise Architect does not allow this direction (it allows only the opposite one Service <- Node). Is it bug of Enterprise Architect, or the metamodel is wrong?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Not so firm with Archimate, but I guess you're talking about the quick linker. They only make suggestions. You can use a relation from the toolbox instead and draw it as needed. Eventually send a bug report.

Comment: Unfortunately link from toolbox does not work. I will try official support, thanks!

Comment: What happens when you use the toolbox instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in build 1421!
https://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/history.html#1421

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it a bug in Sparx. When tested with Visual Paradigm ([certified tool by ArchiMate 3](https://certification.opengroup.org/register/archimate/visual-se-info)) it do allow to create Serving relation from Technology Service to Node.
[image]